# How to handle rel="async-post" dialog in TWebbrowser Delphi(Lazarus))?

Tags: ajax, facebook, delphi, lazarus, twebbrowser

I am making an app for FB to be able to ban people from my facebook page even when they have not yet commented or liked my page. Just like detailed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49g9oP2b7n0). I have a browser written in Lazarus, it logs onto facebook, navigates to page/settings, selects the first user on the "People who like this" list and changes the url and gives me a confirm dialog:
[image: Remove fan Ajax dialog]

The below code creates this dialog:

```
<a class="_54nc" href="/pages/likes/label_fans/?action=remove&amp;page_id=1234567890&amp;user_id=1234567890" rel="async-post" role="menuitem"><span><span class="_54nh">Remove</span></span></a>
```

I would like to parse the popup dialog when it hits OnDocumentComplete event, but I am not able "catch" it. (I guess it is due to the fact this is made with AJAX(?) and with "async-post". )

Anyone knows why?

Thanks in advance,

modzsi

Comment: Is there no API for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can do it via API:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/app/banned

It doesn't mention any restriction to the user id's you can pass in.

I guess you'll need another API call to retrieve the list of people "Who Like This".

Comment: well I have ended up sending SPACE, TAB, TAB, ENTER keyboard event, which worked fine. I tried to find facebook API example for Lazarus/Delphi there is not much out there. Thanks, Zoli!